# Get published apps working with Google Maps Api V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I have followed the steps listed in the other questions but am still at a loss. Would really appreciate some advice.

Hi all, I have my app pretty much ready to go but I am struggling with alpha testing.
for testing, I created a Maps V2 api key using the debug store. This worked on my phone.
I am now ready for other users to test, so I created a new keystore and got my sha1 key with

```
   keytool -list -v -keystore release.keystore
```

I put this into the api console and got a new key. I changed my app to use this key and signed the app using the same keystore.

```
  jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore release.keystore app-release-unsigned.apk release
```

However, the app does not display Google maps on testers phone.
Can anyone help me? Did i do something wrong at one of the stages here?
thanks,
Matt

Comment: What are you making this app with?  In eclipse to get a signed apk use the export method and supply the path and password of the production keystore.  In android studio well I haven't got that far yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the entry in your manifest to use the production key?

Comment: I did,yes. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I would double check the signature and package in the api console against the signature from the signing key. The only time I've seen a blank screen like that is when the signing key does not match the api console entry.

Comment: They match, this is why I am getting so confused.